# Is using the null conditional operator in a destructor bad practice?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I have a class with a *destructor* that I get a **null reference exception** from because the variable I destroy is sometimes `null`.

Is this an appropriate use of the *null conditional operator* to be in the *destructor*?

I'm not even sure if this is an appropriate use of a destructor itself since it is not used to dispose of the actual object it's called on but rather a variable of it.

```
~clsSAPSettings()
{

    mtbTemp?.Close();
}
```

This code was converted from VB6 so I'm trying to figure out how to handle this issue. Any information welcome.

---

**Edit:** The class `mtbTemp` belongs to implements `IDisposable` but *doesn't have* a finaliser/desctructor. It simply closes a connection used in an ORM model.

---

For anyone after a detailed explanation I found a great answer, [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface), it goes into detail about the use of finalizer and how garbage collection actually works.

Comment: If the type of `mtbTemp` is another managed type then this code is wrong. It belongs inside an `IDisposable.Dispose`, not a finalizer

Comment: Using a destructor/finalizer when its not needed is worse

Comment: First of all, the null conditional operator is completely safe to use, the question is why you're calling Close on a different object in the destructor. You shouldn't do this at all. Instead you should implement the dispose pattern correctly.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what a destructor's for, closing down / disposing the resources that an object is using?  I think your usage seems completely valid.

Comment: @Oystein No, it is not. The `Dispose` pattern is.

Comment: No, the destructor is for disposing of **unmanaged resources**, ***not*** managed resources. If you have an `IntPtr` or something similar that is a handle to some unmanaged object, the destructor is one place to close that, in addition to the disposable pattern. You should **not** call into other objects for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Oystein - yes, in C++, no in C#. Question is tagged [tag:c#]

Comment: If the `mtbTemp` object needs to do something in the finalizer, it should have its own destructor, it's not the destructor of `clsSAPSettings` job to do this.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, couldn't this be the case here?  Let's say you have a CommunicationHandler class, with a SerialPort implementation.  Wouldn't the destructor be a proper place to make sure the SerialPort object is closed/disposed?

Comment: The destructor of the SerialPort class, correct, not the destructor of the CommunicationHandler.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/08/how-to-implement-idisposable-and.html

Comment: The class mtbTemp belongs to does implement IDisposable but doesn't have a finaliser/desctructor. It simply closes a connection used in an ORM model. (will add to question)

Comment: Thanks for the information guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not use *any* fields of reference types in the *finalizer*: the order in which GC (Garbage Collector) collects them is *unpredictable* and that's  why

```
 ~clsSAPSettings()
 {
     mtbTemp?.Close();
 }
```

code can well be performed by GC as followes:

1. Collect `mtbTemp` instance
2. Start collecting `this` instance:
3. Call `~clsSAPSettings()`
4. Call `mtbTemp?.Close();` i.e. call a method of the *collected* (destroyed) instance

and you'll have an *unstable hard to find error*. It seems that you are looking for a `IDisposable` interface:

```
 public class clsSAPSettings: IDisposable {
   private MyTemp mtbTemp;

   ... 

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
     if (disposing) { 
        mtbTemp?.Close();

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
     }
   }  

   public void Dispose() {
     Dispose(true);
   }

   //TODO: do you really want finalizer?
   ~clsSAPSettings() {
     Dispose(false);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: observation: there's no point suppressing the finalizer if you're already in the finalizer, so `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` could move to the `if (disposing) {...}` branch - which then exposes that we're not actually doing *anything* in the finalizer case, which makes it very clear that we don't need a finalizer

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Thank you! Nice catch. `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` indeed should be within `if (disposing) {...}`

Comment: Thanks for you answer it's quite informative. I have a question, why do you not trigger the disposal (close()) of mtbTemp from the finalizer? Shouldn't that object (the conntection) be closed when this object is destroyed?

Comment: @George K: I call `Dispose(false);` (not `true`)  from the *finalizer* because `mtbTemp` instance can well be *collected* (i.e. destroyed) and that's why we can't call any method of such an instance. Please, have a look at such scenario in my answer ("1. Collect mtbTemp instance ...").

Comment: @DmitryBychenko So you mean that mtbTemp could be disposed of another way somehow (listed in your answer) hence we can't manually collect it now? Or that it will be collected as part of the destruction of the object it belongs to? I'm still unsure as to why we can't manually collect it since it's not being used anywhere else (only belongs to that object) Thanks Dmitry

Comment: @George K: GC forms the collection of objects to destroy, then destroys them in arbitrary order. That's why we can't be sure in the finalizer that `mtbTemp` has not be destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

Consider:

```
~clsSAPSettings()
{    
    mtbTemp?.Close();
}
```

The problem here isn't the null conditional usage. That doesn't by itself present any issues.

The biggest problem is that in a finalizer you should not touch **any other object**. When the finalizer fires, your object is toast. You no longer have any guarantees about the life of `mtbTemp`, including whether or not it has already been garbage collected, so you **should not touch it**. It might work; it might cause a temporary resurrection, or it might crash horribly.

The correct place to do something like this is in `IDisposable.Dispose`. In the `Dispose` method, that would be absolutely fine:

```
public void Dispose() // where your class : IDisposable
{    
    mtbTemp?.Close();
    mtbTemp = null;
}
```

You probably don't need a finalizer at all. They are *incredibly* rare.

Answer (score 3):

When you are closing streams or other unmanaged objects, you should use the `Dispose` pattern, rather than a destructor. You never know when that destructor will fire.

Regarding the use of the null conditional operator in a destructor: I see no problem with the operator itself. I do with referencing other objects that might already been destructed or in destruction.

Comment: It's only "safe" insofar you're touching objects that don't have destructors but you have to be **super certain that this will always be true**. In general, never touch any *objects*.